# Variable for the suffix of $request_uri that didn't match the location block prefix

Tags: nginx

Suppose I want to move an `/images/` directory to an `images` host so that what was before `http://example.org/images/foo.png` becomes `http://images.example.org/foo.png`.

If I do: `location /images/ { return 301 http://images.example.org$request_uri; }`, the result is a redirect to `http://images.example.org/images/foo.png` which isn't what I want.

[An older question](https://serverfault.com/questions/455799/how-to-remove-location-block-from-uri-in-nginx-configuration) has an answer that suggests using a regexp `location`, but that seems like an overkill.

Is there really no way to refer to `$request_uri` with the `location` prefix chopped off without using regular expressions? Seems like an obvious feature to have.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we could completely eliminate regex for this use case. However, here's an alternative solution that does not use regex `location`, but uses regex **inside** `location` block...

```
location /images/ {
  rewrite "^/images/?(.*)$" "/$1";
  return 301 http://images.example.org$uri;
}
```

Please know that `$uri` doesn't contain `$args`. However, `$request_uri` does. In this alternative solution, we modify the `$uri`, using a regex, before it is processed. `$request_uri` can not be modified, though.

Comment: Thanks. I really want to retain the query string, though. :-(

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Pothis answer](https://serverfault.com/a/547352/96948), you could simply add the `permanent` flag to `rewrite` and directly redirect without using `return`:

```
location /images/ {
  rewrite ^/images/(.*)$ $scheme://images.example.org/$1 permanent;
}
```

This will also keep the parameters with the redirect.

Or, alternatively, if more modifying of the uri is needed, you can simply append `$is_args` and `$args` behind `$uri`:

```
location /images/ {
  rewrite ^/images/(.*)$ /$1;
  [ ... more rewriting ... ]
  return 301 $scheme://images.example.org$uri$is_args$args
}
```