# NGINX, how to strip location prefix in $fastcgi_script_name

Tags: nginx, configuration, fastcgi

I've already read that : [how to remove location block from $uri in nginx configuration?](https://serverfault.com/questions/455799/how-to-remove-location-block-from-uri-in-nginx-configuration)

but is there a way to strip the location blocks's prefix from the $fastcgi_script_name without using regex ?

for example :

```
location /foo/ {
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access-truc.log  FOO;
        alias          /srv/http/php;
        fastcgi_pass   fpm;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include        fastcgi.conf;
}
```

(note : FOO is a log format to display $fastcgi_script_name)

fastcgi.conf has this line :

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

And I want `$fastcgi_script_name` set to only `bar.php` instead of `foo/bar.php` for the url `http://example.com/foo/bar.php`

Answer (score 3):

I have not found a way using `$fastcgi_script_name`, but I actually find that extra level of indirection a bit confusing. I now use the following snippet:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    root        /var/www;
    try_files   $uri $uri/ =404;
    autoindex   on;

    location /openid {
        alias   /opt/openid/www;
        index   index.html index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

A request to `http://host/openid/` will set `SCRIPT_FILENAME` correctly to `/opt/openid/www/index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

```
location /foo/ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^/foo/((.*));
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access-truc.log  FOO;
        alias          /srv/http/php;
        fastcgi_pass   fpm;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include        fastcgi.conf;
}
```